# how to insert a text file in couchdb using nodejs

Tags: node.js, couchdb

I generate a text file using nodejs:

```
 fs.writeFile('file.txt',file, err => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err)
    return
     }
  })
```

then I want to store this file into couchDb. I've tried:

```
couch.insertAttachment("databaseName", "document id", "attachment name", "attachment body", "doc revision").then(({data, headers, status}) => {
    // data is json response
    // headers is an object with all response headers
    // status is statusCode number
}, err => {
    // either request error occured
    // ...or err.code=EFIELDMISSING if either _id or _rev fields are missing
});
```

But it doesn't working for me, I think that I put something wrong.
and how i can get later this file from couchDb?

Comment: insertAttachment is coming from where?

Comment: @AlexisCôté I fixed this issue, but now I want to get all the data from couchdb using reactjs I've tried some solutions but no one work                               
                                                                                                                      
    const nano = require('nano')('http://localhost:5984');
nano.db.use('books').get('2a0580eb69d3153841a74f29c9007d16')
 .then((body) => {
  console.log(body);
 });

Comment: What do you mean by all the data? The line of code you shared should return the appropriate body?